Calculating the probability in an unfair dice roll with given information
Consider an unfair dice with $2^n$ sides with an $n$ bit number on each side. Each side has some associated probability value (with the possibility of value $0$ for some sides).
Given:

For each single bit we are given their probability of two possible values (i.e. 0, 1).
For each pair of bits we are given their probability of all 4 values (i.e. 00, 01, 10, 11). Let the probability of each pair of bits be represented by a fraction. Eg: $P(b_i=0, b_j=0)= \frac {x_{(ij=00)}}{y}$.
Moreover for each pair we are also given the value: $P'(b_i=0, b_j=0)= \frac {\#x_{(ij=00)}+1}{\#2^n}$ where:
$\#2^n$ represents the number of binary strings of length $n$ having non zero probability and $\#x_{(ij=00)}$ represents the number of times the sub-string $(b_i=0, b_j=0)$ occurs in these strings.

Query: Now for a given binary number of length $n$, how do we calculate its probability of occurrence using the above information? I believe its possible to do so, but I am struggling to see how?

I don't see what extra information 3 gives over 2.
However, if the only information you have is about single bits or pairs of bits, you can't deduce the probabilities, even for $n=3$. For example, if you are given $P(b_i=r_i)=1/2$ and $P(b_i=r_i,b_j=r_j)=1/4$ for all $r_i,r_j\in\{0,1\}$, then this is consistent both with all numbers having probability $1/8$ and with all numbers having probability $1/4$ if they have an odd number of one-bits and $0$ otherwise.
[edit] With the new version of 3, you still can't do it. Note that 3 is strictly weaker than being told which values have positive probability, so it's sufficient to show we can't do it even if we know 1 and 2 and that all numbers have positive probability. Modify the above example as follows. For any $0<p<1$, suppose all numbers have probability $p/4$ if they have an odd number of one-bits and $(1-p)/4$ otherwise. Now all numbers have positive probability, the probability of any given single bit value is $1/2$, and the probability of any given pair of bit values is $1/4$, so we can't deduce the value of $p$.

["...and with all numbers having probability 1/4 if they have an odd number of bits and 0 otherwise"] - I am struggling to understand the part "if they have odd number of bits". What does that mean?

I have edited the Q (constraint 3). can you please recheck?

@stack.tarandeep sorry, meant to write "odd number of one-bits". I've edited to deal with the new version of 3.
